# Sending multiple values to firebase with vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

After going through a number of answers on here I still wasnt able to quite figure my issue.

I am working on my first webapp with vue.js and firebase. I was able to to get everything set up to the point of creating new records and sending the name field to the db. I then added another input option with vue select where users can pick a options from a drop down field. When I try to add this second input to the $emit and have it as a property on the created db record, it just keeps duplicating the "assessmentName". I believe this is because I need to do something specific to $emit multiple values, but I just can't seem to figure that out.

https://github.com/mfarry87/AppTrial/blob/master/src/views/Assessments.vue

https://github.com/mfarry87/AppTrial/blob/master/src/App.vue

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your question. Links to external code repositories are ok as supplementary information only

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

To update a Firestore document you'd need to call the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) method with the `{ merge: true }` options object passed in as the `SetOptions` argument.

```
    addAssessment: function(payload) {
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(this.user.uid)
        .collection("assessments")
        .set({
          name: payload,
          criteria: payload,
          createAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        }, { merge: true });
    },
```

That will also create the document if it does not yet exist.